# Installing Wordpress Plugins/Pear Problem on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, wordpress, pear

When I install wordpress plugins, I often get the error

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 
  '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/twitter-for-wordpress/' 
  for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
  /usr/share/wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 473
```

I have Pear installed, but Ubuntu clearly didn't put it in the expected place.  There must be an alias that can fix this, does anyone know what it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Title: "Worpress" should be "Wordpress" - I don't have rep to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a permission issue, and nothing to do with Pear nor the include path - as the error message shows that include_once uses an absolute path and does not need to use the PHP include_path setting.

I suggest that you check that /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/twitter-for-wordpress/ has permissions to allow the web server to read it. This should usually be 755 (rwxr-xr-x in `ls -l`).

Comment: That was the root problem.  I used the wrong user to upload the plugin so it had the wrong permissions - then I needed to actually remove it, it turns out that fixing the permissions doesn't help after you've junked it (according to http://eggblog.invertedegg.com/category/wordpress/).  Seems good now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5, you could try /usr/local/php5/lib/php/PEAR.